# Get PTP4L to fail when it can't connect to an external server

Tags: centos, synchronization

I have a CentOS 7.8 server which has its clock synchronised using the PTP4L PTP service. I'd like the service to fail when it's unable to synchronise with an external server, so I invoke it with `--gmCapable=0`. However, this seems to have no impact. When it can't reach the external time server, it will just resort to using its local clock as grandmaster, giving a false impression that everything works. How can I prevent this?

```
# service ptp4l status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status ptp4l.service
● ptp4l.service - Precision Time Protocol (PTP) service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ptp4l.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-05-12 15:38:33 CEST; 13s ago
 Main PID: 48280 (ptp4l)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ptp4l.service
           └─48280 /usr/sbin/ptp4l -f /etc/ptp4l.conf -i enp65s0f1 --gmCapable=0

May 12 15:38:33 eurex-tr5.veloquant.com systemd[1]: Started Precision Time Protocol (PTP) service.
May 12 15:38:33 eurex-tr5.veloquant.com ptp4l[48280]: [149997.679] selected /dev/ptp1 as PTP clock
May 12 15:38:33 eurex-tr5.veloquant.com ptp4l[48280]: [149997.681] port 1: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
May 12 15:38:33 eurex-tr5.veloquant.com ptp4l[48280]: [149997.681] port 0: INITIALIZING to LISTENING on INIT_COMPLETE
May 12 15:38:40 eurex-tr5.veloquant.com ptp4l[48280]: [150004.734] port 1: LISTENING to MASTER on ANNOUNCE_RECEIPT_TIMEOUT_EXPIRES
May 12 15:38:40 eurex-tr5.veloquant.com ptp4l[48280]: [150004.734] selected local clock 3cecef.fffe.015d03 as best master
May 12 15:38:40 eurex-tr5.veloquant.com ptp4l[48280]: [150004.734] assuming the grand master role
```